# Problem with openssl with ubuntu and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rake

I have a server with RVM installed on it.

Nginx was configured with Passenger to handle ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

I am willing to install a rails 2 application with ruby 1.8.7.

I installed ruby 1.8.7 and install openssl by going to ruby 1.8.7 sources and compiling and installing the .so.

If I start irb and try to require 'openssl' the response if "true"

```
[root@server:/home/redmine/www/redmine-1.0.4/]#irb              
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

But If I try to start for exemple rake gems:install, here is the response.

```
rake gems:install
(in /home/webapps/redmine-1.0.4)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- openssl

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
zsh: exit 1     rake gems:install
```

Is anybody has an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this before. I believe the fix was to:

```
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7*/ext/openssl/
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

If it complains that it needs additional library, you may have to install them. But this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, where other solutions to the same problem didn't. As a side note, I'm using ruby 1.9.2-p0.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what **Olives** posted, for me that required installing the **libssl-dev** package. ruby1.8-dev, libruby1.8 and libopenssl-ruby (virtual package) were already installed.

Am on rvm, ubuntu 10.10, ruby1.8.7, gems 1.4.2

Hope this helps someone stuck on ubuntu  :)